# The repository added using Kubernetes lens are not shown in the charts list

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have added new repository. using the command.
`helm repo add --username <username> <reponame> <url>`.
I am also able to add the same using the lens file->preferences->Kubernetes->Helm charts-> Add custom Helm repo
Check the image below
[Repository added using preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKDyW.png).

Once done I updated the repository list using command
`helm repo update` and then I am also able to list the repo using the helm command `helm search repo -l`
[helm search repo -l result snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhbfg.png)

But the same is not showing in the kubernetes IDE Lens
[Kubernetes lens charts list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzE7P.png).

One this I noticed is the version in the lens chart list doesn't start with any letter but the one that is not shown in the list but in the cli starts with letter "v". I doubt if that could be the cause.

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated

Comment: I tried downloading the first PNG file; what should I do with it?  None of the Helm commands will ever write out image files, and your question might be clearer if you [edit]ed it to include the commands you're running and their output as plain text directly in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I did not add the full command result as the list was very long. And that too I have done all the setup inside ubuntu VM using hyperV and the clipboard is not functional.
The screenshots images are the result of the commands. I can post the complete result in the question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disconnect and reconnect to your cluster within Lens.

This issue is described in the Issues section in the Lens GitHub repository.

See [lens issues at github][1]
https://github.com/lensapp/lens/issues/6566

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).